# Spring Data Neo4j - Indexing and Inheritance

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Lets say i have the following data model:

```
public class A {

    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "property1")
    String property1;
}

public class B extends A {

    @Indexed(indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT, indexName = "property2")
    String property2;
}
```

Can i tell the Spring framework to index `property1` of class B under a different index name?
If not, what would you do in such case? I mean, what would you do if you have few classes that all extends the same base class, but in the same time, all the properties that those classes inherit form the base class should be indexed. I can annotate those properties for indexing only in the base class, and it is very limiting. What can i do?

Thanks.

Comment: Which approach did you choose? Please approve one of the answers if you've used them.

Comment: I'm actually still playing with it, that's why i still didn't accept an answer. I will go more deeply today inside the Level.INSTANCE suggestion to see if it really answer my needs, because as i wrote, i didn't see any influence when i tried it the last time. I will accept one of the answers tonight or tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. Your `property1` will always be indexed in index `property1`. Being able to specify multiple indexes on a single field would probably fix your issue, but it's currently not possible. A while ago, I've raised [an issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATAGRAPH-316) for this, but it's not yet implemented.

If you really want a domain (entity) object approach, you could also opt for the [domain entity approach](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-entities.html). It's not related to Spring or Spring Data Neo4j, but it also does the trick. By manually handling your entities this way, you could also manage the indexes yourself, thus gaining all the flexibility you want.

Just a question, why would you want to specify a different index per subclass?

Comment: As for your last question - Maybe i'm missing something, but i need it in order to be able to make a lookup on class B's property2, in such way that the lookup will be limited only to class B instances/nodes. Maybe there is another way to accomplish what i want?

Comment: You could just use the same index on all your properties. A Lucene query could be like "property2:a_certain_value". In e.g. Cypher this would look like START n=node:your_index("property2:a_certain_value") RETURN n

Comment: but in my case, the index that is named "property2" will hold instances of class A and class B, or any other class that inherit from A, because in all of those classes, the property2 is related to the index that is named "property2".
I want that the property2 of each class will use a different index, so i can lookup the instances of each type separately, and yet keep a neat OOP design.

Comment: Still not quite getting what you really want. Image there's one index you'll use for every property, regarding its class. If you want to retrieve a node of type B, a query like "property2:abc" would do the trick. Image there's a class C that extends from A with a property called "property3". A query like "property3:abc" would again do the trick. Probably I'm missing something, but in essence, I don't think anything's wrong with this approach (or why you really would want to do it otherwise).

Comment: so should i just add another property that holds the type of the node? (and hence the type of the class that this node represents). Does it considered as a good practice?

Comment: Btw, it's always an option to query based on the classname. They are automatically indexed as well. Start your cypher query with "START n=node:__types_("className:A").

Comment: To answer your question, that's already the case. Each node has a property called `__type__` which contains the fully qualified class name. If you want to use this property in a cypher query, make sure to surround it with backticks

Answer (score 2):

The `level` attribute in the index definition annotation can be set to `Level.INSTANCE`. For more help please refer *spring-data-neo4j* documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-neo4j/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#reference%3aprogramming-model%3aindexing)

Here is an excerpt from the doc :

> If a field is declared in a superclass but different indexes for
>   subclasses are needed, the level attribute declares what will be used
>   as index. Level.CLASS uses the class where the field was declared and
>   Level.INSTANCE uses the class that is provided or of the actual entity
>   instance.

Comment: I tried to use it, but i don't see any differences, it looks like the index is still on the class level. Is it possible to give a small example of how to use it, except for expanding the annotation with the LEVEL property? am i missing something? i could not get any more information in the documentation.

Comment: Yeah there are hardly any examples I could find of its usage. This discussion seems to have a mention http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?120071-Inheritance-in-spring-data-neo4j