# Neo4j / Cypher query based on two unrelated nodes returning one result

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

Below, a conceptual example of my context:

I have an abstract class named: `User` (containing an `id` property as String)
I have a `User` subclass named: `FacebookUser`
I have a `User` subclass named: `TwitterUser`

Using Spring-Data-Neo4j, I make `User` a `@NodeEntity`.

I create a test class in order to insert a `FacebookUser` and a `TwitterUser` in the graph.
The whole well occurs => both nodes are inserted and have a **_*type*_** containing the fully qualified name of the subclass.
For instance: `com.myApp.model.user.FacebookUser`.

Now, I want to make this kind of cypher query:
**Retrieve the User whose id = 123**
Thus, I have to find the more efficient way to check for all user nodes (union of `FacebookUser`s and `TwitterUser`), in order to find the unique corresponding record.

I expected to find a way to tell to cypher something like this:
**Take every index matching `FacebookUser`, every index matching `TwitterUser`, and check for the expected node amongst them**

but I didn't manage.

My current query, working, is:

```
@Query("start u=node(*) where has(u.__type__) and u.__type__ =~ '.*User' and has(u.id) and u.id = {0} return u")
```

This one translates to:

**Check for ALL nodes in the graph (I suppose, not efficient at all), then retain those ending with "User" (including FacebookUser and TwitterUser) and check for the right `id`**

Is there a way to only use index nodes in this case, instead of scanning the whole graph?

I was thinking about a way to rename the **_*type*_** property to the full qualified name of the parent class.

Can we do it easily with SDN?

Indeed, since it appears that SDN uses the Java class name associated to the node as the node's index name, it would allow to deal with only one index node for both Facebook and Twitter subtypes:  the **User** index node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use @Indexed on the classes, you should get indexes like TwitterUser etc, that you then can use with your queries. However, there are limitations to the inheritance approach, see [Spring Data Neo4j - Indexing and Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300276/spring-data-neo4j-indexing-and-inheritance) for a related discussion.

Comment: But actually, I want to retrieve an union of FacebookUser and TwitterUser, matching some property, like Id (singleResult in this case). I was thinking about adding a property in my User base class named for instance: "isUser". This one would be indexed (with @Indexed), and be used in my query in order to access (recognize) directly the nodes corresponding to a user(union of Facebook and Twitter users), thus avoiding scanning the whole graph. __type__ serving only to retrieve the type of class in order to process mapping to Java. Would it be an efficient solution? Thanks :)

Comment: wanted to say __ type __  not **type**

Comment: I think that would be quite ok. Test it!